# Change HTML element using XHttpRequest from HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, html, xmlhttprequest

I want to be able to enter a name into a form and have a message sent back underneath saying "Your name is" [name] ", right?" I built this little test program that I plan on incorporating back into the main code but haven't had much luck with it. I am using the POST method.

```
<HTML XMLns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xHTML"> 
<head> 
  <title>A Simple Ajax Example</title> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="xhr.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="simpleajax.js"> </script>
</head> 
<body>
  <h1>Fetching data with Ajax</h1>
  <iframe name="iFrame" style="display: none;"></iframe>
  <form method="post" action="data.php" target="iFrame">
    <label>User Name:</label>
    <input id="namefield" type="text" name="namefield">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Fetch" onclick="loadDoc(namefield.value);">
  </form>
  <div> 
    <p id="targetDiv">The fetched data will go here.</p>  
  </div> 
</body> 
</HTML>
```

And the javascript...

```
function loadDoc(name) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var firstName = name;
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("targetDiv").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };

  xhttp.open("POST", "data.php?namefield=" + firstName, true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Prevent the default event in your javascript.

Comment: when you submit a form, it loads the page specified in `action`

Comment: @MacroMan - removing action wont prevent the submit from loading something ... without action, it will load the current page, because action "default" value is the current URL .... preventing the default event action is the right advice though :p

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah sorry, I just read that back... (facepalm)

Comment: try `loadDoc(namefield.value); return false;` ...

Comment: ...or add `onsubmit="return false;"` to the form tag.

Comment: Even with `onsubmit="return false;"` it still doesn't print "Your name is [name], right?" and only prints "Your name is ,right?"

Answer (score 0):

Here is what input type submit does from MDN :

```
<input> elements of type "submit" are rendered as buttons.
When the click event occurs (typically because the user clicked the button), 
the user agent attempts to submit the form to the server.
```

So to change that, one of the ways is to return false in the onclick handler ex:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Fetch" onclick="loadDoc(namefield.value);return false;">
```

Or you can use Button Element instead of submit which will give more meaning for what you need to do:

```
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc(namefield.value);">Fetch</button>
```

Comment: On the main piece of code, it needs to submit as the form is getting filled into a database. Will it still submit to the DB?

Comment: You didn't mention in your test case any DB activities, but you can do that in your XMLHttpRequest Call and return your result normally. So your call will store in DB then when its back successfully it will append the mentioned name to the DOM.